# What's the best way to get academic references for a masters program 2-3 years in the future?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, recommendation-letter, time-off

I graduated with a BSc approximately one year ago and have been considering my career options since. I have finally decided that I would like to enroll in a masters program, however I likely won't be able to apply for another year or two down the road.

Regretfully, I was a quiet student during my undergrad, not knowing for sure whether I had it in me to pursue a masters degree in the future. As a result, I did not make as many connections or relationships with professors as I now wish I had when I had the chance.

The program I am interested in requires two academic references. My fear is that my lack of overall impression, despite obtaining decent grades, will have resulted in my professors being unable to relate my name to my face and will therefore be unable to provide me with a suitable reference when required for submission a year or two from now.

Can anybody provide me with any suggestions? Should I reach out to potential professors now to see if 1.) they even remember me, or 2.) if they are comfortable with providing references in a year or two's time? I'm concerned if I ask in a year or two when the references are required, they will undoubtedly have forgotten me.

An important note may be that I am moving out of the town where I attended university in a couple months, which will likely make it harder to redevelop any relationships in person if required.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest that you make the connections immediately since you are moving out of the area. Take this time to meet with three or four of the professors in whose classes you did the best or got the most out of.  I would see if you can get some face to face time so that they can put a name to a face.  You might be surprised that they actually do remember you! And then explain to them your dilemma and ask them what you asked here... Would they be comfortable giving you a reference?  I've found in my experience that most people want to help when they can... they just need to be asked. Good luck!